# Jmeter2.9 with IBM MQ Not Connecting

Tags: jmeter, jndi, ibm-mq

I am trying to use JMeter to work with IBM MQ.

As per the [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0808_vandekuil/0808_vandekuil.html) I created the JNDI Bindings.

Now I am trying to connect JMeter using the JNDI Bindings. I give the QCF (Queue Connection Factory), but it is throwing an error

"Response message: java.lang.IllegalStateException: QueueConnectionFactory expected, but got javax.naming.Reference"

I searched around a lot, but didnt find anything. I looked at source code for Sampler and it looks like it is not able to find the Connection Factory from the JNDI.

Any idea what could i be missing? I Didnt know if the Configuration details would help, if it would i can provide that.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by copying all the MQ Jars (that comes with a complete Websphere MQ installation) and placing them into JMeter/Lib.

Now it works fine.

Thanks for anyone who viewed this. Hope my answer may provide some light to others who may encounter the same problem.

Comment: Hey Mandy,  Did you use JMS point-point or Publisher/Subscriber?Could you please provide your configuration setting screenshots.I have to do test for WebSphere MQ .I appreciate your help!

Comment: @rpagadala i used JMS point-point. It was long time ago, i dont have configuration screenshots. Are you having any specific problem while you are trying to configure?